# Is there a Twitter Bootstrap class that means "initially hidden"?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3, I have an element on a page I want to show later in response to the user clicking a button.  Example:

```
<div id="search_results">
... gets populated from ajax data later ...
</div>

<button id="search_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Search</button>

<script>
$('#search_button').click(function() {
    // ... do the call to search
    // and in the callback: 
    $('#search_results').show();
});
</script>
```

The search_results div should be initially hidden.  Is there some normal/best practice way of doing this with bootstrap?

Yes, I do realize I can just put style="display:none" on search_results, but is that the best way to do it?  It would seem to be a bit better to have a style that semantically means "initially hidden".  (NOTE: The hidden or hide classes don't do this as they are !important and show(), toggle(), etc. use an inline style which does not override them, i.e. setting "hidden" as the class makes it unshowable from jQuery.)

Comment: there is a class `hidden` that you can add, and remove that class when you want to `show`. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-show-hide

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking through the source suggests either `.collapse` or `.invisible` are options, depending on whether you want `display: none;` behaviour or `visibility: hidden;` behaviour, respectively.

Update, 2016-03-08: Early adopters of Bootstrap v4 should note that the rule for `.invisible` is now `visibility: hidden !important;`. (`.collapse` is unchanged.)

Comment: Nice!  "collapse" - makes perfect sense, very similar concept to "initially hidden".  (And it works)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `hidden` class, to hide the element

```
<div id="search_results" class="hidden">
... gets populated from ajax data later ...
</div>
```

then

```
$('#search_button').click(function () {
    // ... do the call to search
    // and in the callback: 
    $('#search_results').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v3qp2rkj/)

[Showing and hiding content](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-show-hide)

Comment: This does not work, because hidden has !important on it (noted in the link as well).  And jQuery's show() sets an inline style but not !important, which is less specific.  I.e. it doesn't work.

Comment: Right - it of course can be made to work by removing the class - I see your edit.  Was just wondering if there is a class that actually means that it's initially hidden and then can be overridden by another inline style.  Doesn't look like it.  Will accept if nobody comes along with a better answer.

Comment: @bgp that I don't think so... of course you can write one of your own right? :)

Comment: Oh you know how these styles are, so many extra keystrokes... ;)